# how to get the local time in simple meridian format in php

Tags: php

can u please help me out with the codes to get the present time n the meridian format..like its 1920 hours or 07.20 pm... how to make it independent of the location .. meaning... the users everywhere round the world shud get their local times....

Comment: This can be a user/set preference. You can do some IP-Sniffing and try to match it to the user but you should always have a place for the user to define it's own local time.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, PHP has no way of telling what the user's local time is.

I suggest [using Javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_date) for that.

Answer (score 0):

If you ask `time()`, it will always give you the time on the server.

If you want the users localized time, you'll need to:

- depend on the clienttime with javascript, but this might not be the correct time
- calculate the correct time by the user's time zone, but I don't have a clue how this can be done.